# Поиск по 2 полям из одной таблицы на Yii2 без Gridview

Tags: yii2, search

Хочу организовать поиск без использования Gridview и вывести результаты поиска в массиве
Есть таблица с такими полями как id... from , to и другие.
Нужно организовать поиск по 2 полям, так что если введенные данные с обеих полей( from и to) одной таблицы есть в базе вывести их в массиве.

Поиск пока не работает. После нажатия на поиск страница обновляется и остается на site/index(без вывода какого либо результата) не знаю почему помогите пожалуйста кто может. Очень хочется чтобы поиск заработал

**код из siteController.php**

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    $driver = new Driver();

    if ($driver->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $driver = Driver::find()
            ->where(['from' => $driver->from])
            ->andWhere(['to' => $driver->to])
            ->one();

        return $this->render('search', ['driver' => $driver]);
    }
    else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Input data not found' );
    }
}
```

**код из models/Driver.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use Yii;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "driver".
 *
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $from
 * @property string $to
 * @property string $data
 * @property string $about
 * @property string $car
 */
class Driver extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'driver';
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
//            [['from', 'to', 'data', 'about', 'car'], 'required'],
            [['about'], 'string'],
            [['from', 'to', 'data', 'car'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'from' => 'From',
            'to' => 'To',
            'data' => 'Data',
            'about' => 'About',
            'car' => 'Car',
        ];
    }

}
```

**код из site/index.php**

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\Driver;
/* @var $driver app\models\Driver */
?>
<?php
$driver = new Driver;
?>

      <div class="row">

          <div>
              <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <?= $form->field($driver, 'from')->label('От')->textInput(['class' => 'input form-control']) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <?= $form->field($driver, 'to')->label('До')->textInput(['class' => 'input form-control']) ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2" align="left" style="margin-top: 30px">
                      <input type="image" src="<?= \Yii::getAlias('@web/images/button_search.png')?>" class="icon_button" alt="Поиск" >
                  </div>
              </div>

              <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
          </div>

      </div>
```

**код из site/search.php**

```
    <?php
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

$this->title = "Поиск";

$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'description',
    'content' => 'driver',
]);
$this->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'keywords',
    'content' => 'driver',
])

?>
<?php

?>

    <?php if (!$driver) { ?>
        <p>Ничего не найдено</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach ($driver as $one){
        $from = $one -> from;
        $to = $one -> to;
        $data = $one -> data;
        ?>

    <div class="one">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><?=$from?></p>
        </td>
        <td class="right">

        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <p><?=$to?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <div class="">
            <?=$data?> <br>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php  }?> 
<?php } ?>
```

**и site/found_drivers.php**
он теперь пустой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно составляете запросы и некорректно используете **ActiveRecord**.

Ваш запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM driver WHERE from = "<from>" AND to = "<to>";
```

Для формирования его в **ActiveRecord** требуется:

```
$journey = Driver::find()
    ->where(['from' => $driver->from])
    ->andWhere(['to' => $driver->to])
    ->one();
```

В итоге ваш метод в *SiteController* будет выглядеть так:

```
public function actionDriver()
{
     $driver = new Driver();

     if ($driver->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

         $driver = Driver::find()
             ->where(['from' => $driver->from])
             ->andWhere(['to' => $driver->to])
             ->one();

         return $this->render('driver', ['driver' => $driver]);
     }
}
```

Также советую перечитать [документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) по Yii2

Comment: Спасибо приму во внимание но вот ничего не отображается просто белый лист в браузере что может быть не так?

Comment: @IldarNasurlaev Вы всегда можете посмотреть в чем проблема в логах, которые находятся в директории  app/runtime/logs. Также советую установить и настроить Xdebug. И, наконец, проверьте в файле app/config/main.php подключен ли у вас debug в разделах 'bootstrap' и 'modules'

Comment: Сделал update есть некоторые продвижения но поиск все таки еще не работает

Comment: @IldarNasurlaev Вы можете посмотреть, какой запрос создаёт AR следующей коммандой: Driver::find()->where(['from' => $driver->from])->andWhere(['to' => $driver->to])->)->createCommand()->getSql();

Comment: сделал update изменил site/search.php добавил переменные в нее `<?php foreach ($driver as $one){
        $from = $one -> from;
        $to = $one -> to;
        $data = $one -> data;
        ?>

            <?php return $this -> render('found_drivers', [
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $data
        ]); ?>
        <?php  }?>`

Comment: После переноса всего содержимого из site/found_drivers на site/search заработало)